# clear shopping cart is not working

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, shopping-cart, shopping

My `cart.phtml` already have `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` but still clear shopping cart & update shopping cart is not working.

Please, give me better solution over this.
Thank You in advance!

Comment: What magento version are you working on, and you have done any other changes?

Comment: are you facing this issue after magento upgrade ?

Comment: Magento version 1.8.1.0

Comment: Do you have any extension installed related to product/cart, try disabling that, as it does not seem to be breaking.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your theme directory, in the file:

```
/app/design/frontend/yourthemepackage/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

or in the file:

```
/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/checkout/cart.phtml
```

Just place on line 50 just after `getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">` paste the below code:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

it will work fine now.

Comment: Thanx its working :-)

Comment: GENIUS - ran into this with varnish + turpentine this answer solved my problem THANK YOU +1

Comment: It works, you save my day.